# How do I return number of members from user controls in ASP.NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, asp.net-membership

Which class member can I use to return the number of members, that have signed up for an account?   (I'm using the built-in membership/profile/log-in stuff..)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Membership.GetAllUsers().Count` should work